# Excel slowed down after using 'on active cell change' macro

Tags: vba, excel

I recently experimented with a macro that runs every time the active cell column changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Integer
    cell = ActiveCell.Column
    Select Case cell
    'code
    End Select
End Sub
```

I quickly realized that this slows down Excel by a lot, so I turned the macro off. The problem is that it must have turned something on, because now every time I change the active cell in any Excel file on my computer, it loads a little bit, like if that macro was still running.

I deleted the macro, restarted the computer, but nothing.

If I manually turn off events (Application.EnableEvents = False), this problem goes away, but as soon as I open another Excel file (any file, not just the one I wrote the macro in), it turns back on.

What have I done and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, it seems that you have Saved the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to a `personal.xlsb` file.
Find it, delete the code and enjoy your Friday!

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I think I don't have a personal.xlsb - Office Support says View > Unhide would show it, but there is no hidden window there. I also do not recall saving any macro there, although of course I might have done it by accident. I performed a search on the whole PC, but nothing shows up.

It should be somewhere in C:\Documents and Settings, but I cannot access that folder (company laptop). Is that the problem? I think it would still show in the Unhide window if I had one.

Comment: @kdava - try to record a macro and store it to the `Personal Macro Workbook` (point 3 of the Microsoft link). Then find the workbook and check, whether you have some events or not.

Comment: Done, but it was empty except for the macro I recorded.

Comment: @kdava - record, save, close. Then try to find the Personal Macro Workbook with the recorded macro and look for an event.

Comment: I have found the issue - there was an add-in installed, I turned it off and now everything is ok. The add-in might have picked something up that stuck, because it was working fine before I wrote that macro. Thank you for your help.